# Trigger to run stored procedure SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have staging table for data, every month company insert data in staging table. I am using a stored procedure to copy data form staging to multiple tables. I want to create a trigger to run these stored procedures.

For example my staging table `blk_data` and my stored procedure is  `sp_payment`, I tried to using something like

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects
           WHERE name = 'trg_pay' AND type = 'TR')
   DROP TRIGGER blk_data
GO

CREATE TRIGGER trg_pay
ON payroll
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
   sp_payment
GO
```

but it doesn't work. Please correct me.

Thanks!

Comment: what does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: You seem to be missing the EXEC statement. A procedure will execute in SSMS without the exec statement but in a trigger it doesn't know what you want to do.

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter: i was created . But when i insert more data in staging table trigger didn't run store procedure .

Comment: Why do you drop trigger blk_data before create trigger trg_pay?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things... is this your intended deployment script for this trigger?  I'm having trouble understanding what else this could be.

Your original statement:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects
      WHERE name = 'trg_pay' AND type = 'TR')
   DROP TRIGGER blk_data
GO
CREATE TRIGGER trg_pay
ON payroll
FOR INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE
AS
   sp_payment

GO
```

and your original question:

> I have staging Table for data, every month company insert data in staging table . I am using Stored Procedure to copy data form staging to multiple tables. I want to create a Trigger to run these Stored procedures. For example my Staging table Name is "blk_data" and my store procedure is "sp_payment" , i tried to using something like

1. Why are you dropping the trigger blk_data?
2. Why are you creating the trigger on the `payroll` table when you state in your question the staging table name is `blk_data`?  (at least that's how i'm interpreting it)
3. You're missing an exec.

I would think you would actually want something like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects
      WHERE name = 'trg_pay' AND type = 'TR')
   DROP TRIGGER trg_pay
GO
CREATE TRIGGER trg_pay
ON blk_data
FOR INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE
AS
   exec sp_payment

GO
```

this will mean any changes to data in the `blk_data` table would cause an execution of the stored procedure `sp_payment`.  I'm assuming this is your intention?

Answer (score 2):

You need to exec it:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects
      WHERE name = 'trg_pay' AND type = 'TR')
   DROP TRIGGER trg_pay
GO
CREATE TRIGGER trg_pay
ON payroll
FOR INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE
AS
   exec sp_payment

GO
```

> You do not have to specify the
>   EXECUTE keyword when you execute stored procedures when the statement
>   is the first one in a batch.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx

Other way you have to.

Comment: Maybe "drop trigger tr_pay"?